# Converting ssh.PublicKey to string OpenSSH format with comment

Tags: go, ssh, public-key-encryption, openssh

I am trying to convert an ssh.PublicKey object to an ssh rsa string in my go service which I want to send over the network to other service that would authorise this request using the supplied public key. For this I need the exact rsa string in open ssh format like below in the authorising service

```
ssh-rsa <pubkey> <comment>
```

I tried this `fmt.Println(base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(key.Marshal()))` but that truncates the comment part, thus leading to authorisation issues.

Should I ignore the comment in the auth service when doing an equality check?

Comment: There is no "comment part" in the public key. It looks like you want the openssh format from  [`ssh.MarshalAuthorizedKey`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#MarshalAuthorizedKey)?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to use the `ssh.MarshalAuthorizedKey` to generate the string in the desired format! In your authorization service,when comparing the received public key with the stored ones, you can ignore the comment part if it's not relevant to your authorization logic, because the public key itself should be sufficient for the comparison!

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/rsa"
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
)

func main() {
    //generating an RSA key pair
    privateKey, _ := rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader, 2048)
    publicKey := &privateKey.PublicKey

    //converting the public key to an SSH RSA string
    authorizedKeyBytes := ssh.MarshalAuthorizedKey(publicKey)
    authorizedKeyString := string(authorizedKeyBytes)

    fmt.Println(authorizedKeyString)
}
```